# MongoDB command in PHP (db.serverStatus().uptime)

Tags: php, mongodb

Im trying to get the uptime from a remote server, so far im able to get the version through the execution of a command. But I can't get it to run this command to get the uptime.

```
<?php
    
    
    $mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<DNS>:<PORT>');
    
    echo "Connection to database successfully\n";
    
    $admin = $mongo->admin;
    
    $cursor= $admin->command(array('serverStatus().uptime'));
    
    var_dump($cursor);
    
    $response = $cursor->toArray();
    
    var_dump($response);
    
?>
```

Im running a var_dump to see what it returns, it does return a int but is far too big to be the actual uptime.

Comment: The result is in milliseconds, which you'll need to divide by 60 or 3600 or 86400 to get the result in either mins or hrs or days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the server uptime, execute serverStatus command and then you can fetch uptime in milliseconds like this

```php
try {
    $dsn = "mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/";
    
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager($dsn);
    $command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['serverStatus' => 1]);
    $cursor = $manager->executeCommand('admin', $command);

    foreach ($cursor->toArray() as $server) {
        //print_r($server->uptime / 60. " Minutes");
        //print_r($server->uptime / 3600. " Hours");
        print_r($server->uptime / 86400. " Days");
    }
} catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {  
    print_r($e);
}
```